# Max Sum Contiguous Subarray in C

Tags: c, arrays

The problem is to find the max contiguous sub array sum; I am getting 0 as the output and in some case a random number(I checked for going out of array bound but all seems fine).

I saw the similar problems asked in STACK OVERFLOW but most of them was for small input and in other programming language.

here is my code:

```
int maxSubArray(const int* A, int n1) 
{
    int i,j,max[n1],L;

    for (i=0;i<n1-1;i++)
    {    
        int sum=A[i]+A[i+1];
        max[i]=sum;
        for(j=i+1;j<n1-1;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+A[j+1];
            if(sum>max[i])
            {
                max[i]=sum;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<n1;i++)
    {  
        L=max[0];
        if(max[i]>L)
        {
            L=max[i];
        }
    }

    return(L);
}
```

Please help me finding what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Hello, I suggest you read this article [Largest Sum Contiguous Subarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/)

Comment: Does "contiguous sub array" mean that it has to be at least 2 entries? Normally I would assume that 0 and 1 entries is valid too.

Comment: it has to be atleast 2 entries

Comment: When you are looking over the array again to see which entry is the largest, you look into entry n1-1 but that entry is not defined. So in the second big loop you should run to `i<n1-1`.

Comment: And also in that second big loop you are setting L=max[0] on each iteration. That should be before the loop.

Comment: @BerndElkemann Oh yes,thanks

Answer (score 0):

- the OP really wants to sum at least 2 entries (not 0 or 1).
- The L=max[0] needs to be before the second outer loop (in which we determine which entry is largest).
- The second outer loop goes one entry too far, because the last entry is not defined (because of the 2 entries rule)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudocode:

current_sum = 0

best_sum = 0

Iterate through array:

if current sum less than current sum + array[i]

```
current_sum = current_sum + array[i]
```

if best sum less than current sum

```
best_sum = current_sum
```